# I used the function "putchar()" to print the result of a test, but i got a question mark instead

Tags: c, putchar

So like what the title suggest i have tried to use `putchar()` to  print a result of a not equal to test `!=` but the output i got is a question mark.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

    int c;
    c = getchar() != EOF;
    putchar(c);
}
```

I have used `printf()` and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{

    printf("%d",getchar()!=EOF);
}
```

My question is: **Why it doesn't work with** `putchar`**?**

Comment: Since the code version with printf "works" please explain what it does and what exactly you are trying to achieve by `getchar()!=EOF`. Maybe explain by adding equivalent `()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I am trying to answer the exercice 1-7 in **The C programming language** book which ask to verify that the expression```getchar()!=EOF``` is 0 or 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, accepting that the comparison `getchar()!=EOF` will yield a Boolean value, which will be converted to either `1` (for true) or `0` (false) when interpreted as any integral type, the statement:

```
printf("%d",getchar()!=EOF);
```

prints the value of this conversion as a ***formatted*** integer - so you will see "1" or "0" printed.

However, the statement:

```
putchar(c);
```

outputs the the actual character represented by the value of `c` (frequently, but not necessarily, the ASCII value). The characters represented by `0` and `1` are not 'printable' characters, so your console will display something indicating that - in your case, a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

`putchar` sends a character, identified by its code value, to standard output. 0 and 1 are not, in most C implementations, codes for the characters “0” or “1”. To get a code value for “0” or “1” from an `int c` containing 0 or 1, use `'0' + c`.

`printf("%d",getchar()!=EOF)` formats the argument value as a decimal numeral, so it generates the appropriate characters.